# Changing font of dmenu in xmonad

Tags: xmonad

I am using xmonad and dmenu and by default the modMask-p combination launches dmenu. However, the font is too small for me, and I cannot figure out how to change it. I can run `dmenu_run -fn "-misc-fixed-*-*-*-*-15-*-*-*-*-*-*-*"` from the command line and dmenu appears with a larger font, but when I go into my xmonad.hs file and do a

```
defaultConfig { ...stuff...} `additionalKeys` [((mod4Mask, xK_p), spawn "dmenu_run -fn \"-misc-fixed-*-*-*-*-15-*-*-*-*-*-*-*\"")]
```

and then `xmonad --recompile` nothing seems to change and no error message appears.

Appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove both `\"` around the font string.

This works for me:

```
((mod4Mask, xK_p), spawn "dmenu_run -fn -*-terminus-*-r-*-*-12-*-*-*-*-*-*-* -nb bisque3 -nf grey35 -sb bisque1 -sf grey10")
```

Comment: or even better use instead of dmenu **xmonad.prompt.shell**